# Escape Mustache variable containing apostrophe for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mustache

I have a variable (`{{title}}`) which contains an apostrophe. Mustache escapes this as `&#39;`.

However, the following template results in a JavaScript error (`Expected token ')'`):

```
<a href="javascript:confirm('{{title}}?');">{{title}}</a>
```

After Mustache rendering, the syntax error is clear (`'Joe's Lame?'`):

```
<a href="javascript:confirm('Joe's Lame?');">Joe's Lame</a>
```

I am still learning Mustache and while this example is contrived, what is the proper way to escape variables in these situations.

The [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2tQGt/) for reference.

Comment: Interesting! I suppose this is not possible with Mustache. Should not be much of a problem with Handlebars (`Handlebars.registerHelper`)...

Comment: @hgoebl, the solution does not have to be Mustache.

Comment: Then you should have a look at [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/). It's a superset of Mustache and can be extended very easily. You would have to create and register a helper-function like `escapeJs` and in your template use it like `{{escapeJS title}}`. If I find time I'll fork your fiddle...

Comment: I know this is only a dumb workaround (replacing the apostrophe problem with another character), but a quick & dirty solution would be: `"<a href='javascript:confirm(\"{{title}}\");'>{{title}}</a>"`.

Comment: @hgoebl, I agree that would work. I was asking if JavaScript or Mustache had something I was missing.

Answer (score 7):

**P/S: I know this is an old post, just in case someone find it useful. Like myself, I found your post too before I realized about the triple brackets solution.**

In Mustache, just use the triple brackets, no need to be so headache:

```
{{{title}}}
```

But for your case, I don't think by simply escaping the single quote is enough. You should also reverse your single and double quotes like this:

```
<a href='javascript:confirm("{{{title}}}?");'>{{{title}}}</a>
```

Comment: "*You should also reverse your single and double quotes*" - that shouldn't matter. The escaping needs to be able to handle both.

Comment: @Bergi : The person who asked the question only asked for escaping the `{{title}}` variable, not the entire anchor tag. The above answer offered the solution to escape the whole anchor tag and didn't get marked as answer either.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "entire" anchor tag, and I think it's irrelevant what the OP exactly asked for - they want a working solution, and the only correct solution does first escape the value in the js string literal, and then the js code in the html attribute. It needs to work with `title` containing apostrophes, quotes, angle brackets, backslashes, anything.

Comment: @Bergi :  My answer is direct related to Mustache way of solution and it's working with necessary native solution to the JS string. I do not want to create unnecessary conversation here that may violate the rules in Stack Overflow, but no escape was asked for the whole JS string except the `{{title}}`

Comment: I'm really not sure - we only care about the attribute value, not the entire tag? And no, your solution is not working when `title` contains double quotes. If you say that's what the OP asked for and want to provide a broken solution, please at least add a warning about XSS.

Comment: @Bergi : No, obviously, the OP title says **apostrophe**. Why don't you ask the OP to send you the entire project code and resolve for him as well? I was just answer according to SCOPE, nothing wrong with my answer. If you want to make this a long conversation, I accompany you.

Comment: This answer is a **security issue**, knowingly or not and in scope of the question or not, that's all I care about. We are not here to help *only* the OP, but every programmer who stumbles upon this Q&A.

Answer (score 3):

So if it doesn't have to be Mustache, you can use a superset of Mustache called [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/).

First register a Handlebars helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('escapeJs', function(str) {
    return str.replace(/[\'\"\\\/]/gm, function (c) {
        return '\\' + c;
    });
});
```

And you call your helper like this `{{escapeJs title}}`:

```
var view = {
    title: "Joe's Lame\"\\/€"
};

var template = Handlebars.compile(
    "<a href=\"javascript:confirm('{{escapeJs title}}');\">{{title}}</a>");
var output = template(view);
```

View it live in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X8fqK/1/).

Mustache is really cool and it's available in almost any programming language. Handlebars is awesome and is used e.g. in [Backbone Thorax](http://thoraxjs.org/) and [assemble](http://assemble.io/), a powerful static web-site generator.

**Edit: Alternative Solution**

When using ECMAScript 5 (and with shim/shiv/polyfills that should be working with IE8 as well), one could prepare the view-object for Mustache in the following way. I admit, that this is not a very handy solution, but when producing JavaScript output is rare, it might be acceptable IMO.

```
function escapeJs (str) {
    return str.replace(/[\'\"\\\/]/gm, function (c) {
        return '\\' + c;
    });
}

var view = {
    title: "Joe's Lame"
};

Object.defineProperty(view, 'titleJsEnc', {
    enumerable: false,
    get: function () { return escapeJs(this.title); }
});

var output = Mustache.render(
    "<a href=\"javascript:confirm('{{titleJsEnc}}');\">{{title}}</a>", view);
```

Defining a new property (via [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)) does the trick. One could write a generic object decorator which defines a getter for each real property returning the escaped string value.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wg7KX/2/)

**Edit: Alternative: Wait for a new version of Mustache**

Once this [pull-request](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/pull/358) is merged and a new version of Mustache is published, this problem should be solved in a "Mustache native way".

Comment: + However, when I commented that the solution didn't have to be Mustache I didn't mean it could be *any* technology. I'd like to solve the problem with one of the technologies I am using.