# Mustache template escape html code

Tags: javascript, jquery, mustache

I have javascript array like this,

```
[button: "M'AVERTIR"]
```

When i tried to display the string in mustache template. It displaying the below format.

```
M&#039;AVERTIR
```

My mustache template code is,

```
{{=<% %>=}}
<%button%>
<%={{ }}=%>
```

Is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: you can try using {{{ }}}. they render html as html.

Comment: Yes. I've tried. However, the text displaying like this only M&#039;AVERTIR.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23662608/escape-mustache-variable-containing-apostrophe-for-javascript

Comment: {{=<% %>=}}
<%&button%>
<%={{ }}=%>   I've tried like this. It works. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried like this,

```
{{=<% %>=}}
<%& button %>
<%={{ }}=%>
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
* {{default_tags}}
{{=<% %>=}}
* <% erb_style_tags %>
<%={{ }}=%>
* {{ default_tags_again }}
```

[See the page](https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html)